# For loop to create a key value-pair in TypeScript (ES 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to define a datastructure where I can recieve the name using a specific ID.
I try to add them to a dict here and want to get back the name

```
    let dict = [];
    for (let company of this.listOfCompanies) {
      dict.push({
        [company.id]: companyName
      });
    }
```

Is this the correct way to do it? And how do I get back my name? Can I do like this?

```
console.log(dict[83519952]);
```

Comment: your dict should actually be an Object, rather than an array so you can search any name in `O(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a type to help linter and compiler and use object instead of array.

```
let dict: { [id: number]: string } = {};
for (const company of this.listOfCompanies) {
  dict[company.id] = company.name;
}
```

`dict` also can be declared as `const` if you are not planning to change the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let dict = [];
    for (let company of this.listOfCompanies) {
      dict[company.id]= companyName;
      });
    }
```

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try by considering `dict` as an object rather than an array. You can do this by using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

This is an example in vanilla es6 demonstrating this:

```js
const listOfCompanies = [{"id": 100, "companyName": "foo"}, {"id": 101, "companyName": "bar"}];
const dict = listOfCompanies.reduce((acc, {id, companyName} ) =>{ //destructuring id and companyName keys from the object to variables
   acc[id] = companyName;
   return acc;
},{});
console.log(dict[100]);
console.log(dict[101]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank  you for great answers. I ended up using a Map (which had some more nice features of not throwing errors when undefined):

I'll define this:

```
companiesNames: Map<number, string> = new Map<number, string>();
```

Then in my function:

```
    for (let company of this.listOfCompanies) {
      this.companiesNames.set(+company.id, company.name);
    }
    console.log(this.companiesNames.get(83519952));
```

That worked fine but is there any reason this would be a bad choice?